# ViewModelProvider.get always gives unresolved reference

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata, android-lifecycle

I'm trying to use ViewModel library in my app, I have created a class `MainActivityViewModel` which extends ViewModel class. When trying to instantiate the `MainActivityViewModel` class inside `MainActivity` by using `ViewModelProvider.get(Class)` the get method always results in an unresolved reference

`MainActivityViewModel` class:

```
class MainActivityViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private lateinit var mWords: MutableLiveData<List<Word>>

    fun getWords(): LiveData<List<Word>>{
        return mWords
    }
}
```

`MainActivity` class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var mMainActivityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val recycler = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler)
    recycler.adapter = RecyclerAdapter(this)
    recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)

    mMainActivityViewModel = ViewModelProvider.get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
}
```

}
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here,

the dependencies used for liveData:

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
def arch_version = "2.1.0"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5"
// ViewModel
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
// LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
// Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not static/companion object method

Comment: @Selvin can you elaborate more please?

Comment: About what? You need instance of this class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in context, so ViewModel knows when it can be destoryed.

```
mMainActivityViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass owner for viewmodel provider (Activity/fragment)

```
mMainActivityViewModel= ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
```

You can alternatively declare it like this

```
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels  //use this import

val mMainActivityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel by viewModels() // no need to initialize it again
```